# Pinging a random non-bot user in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Code:

```
import random
user = random.choice(message.guild.members)
await message.channel.send('Hello ' + user.mention)
```

My question is how do I ping a random, non-bot user in `Discord.py`?

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a user is a bot with [Member.bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.bot) which returns a bool

Use a list comprehension to sort the members in the guild that are not bots(user accounts) and then use `random.choice` accordingly.

```py
import random

humans = [m for m in message.guild.members if not m.bot]
random_member = random.choice(humans)

await message.channel.send(f"Hello {random_member.mention}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an if statement to see if the user is a bot.

```py
if not user.bot:
    await message.channel.send('Hello ' + user.mention)
```

You can get more information [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.abc.User.bot)